# What is this object in BG2?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

In a video of someone's gameplay, I saw this:

[image]

What is this object?

Comment: That looks like a key or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the vanilla game, it's the Wand of Wonder, found in the Mind Flayers Lair (Temple District Sewers). Each time it is used, it produces a random effect.
Source : http://mikesrpgcenter.com/bgate2/wands.html